# PowerMockito is not mocking a private method after upgrade and instead calling the real method

Tags: java, powermockito

PowerMockito is not mocking a private method after upgrade and instead calling the real method and throwing a nullpointer exception since method arguments are null.
I was using powermock-module-junit4:1.7.4, org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4'. org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4 version and in my test I am using below:

```
PowerMockito.when(myClass.class, "getPaymentBeans", ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenThrow(new NullPointerException()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

but after upgrade to mockito-core', version: '3.7.7, org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9 and org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.9.

It stopped mocking the private method and instead throw NullPointerException on the method call since the arguments of the methods are null.

here is the sample example:

```
    public class MyClass{
 
    public ModelBean process(){
 
        //some code
        ModelBean[] result = getPaymentBeans(data[], new String[]{"test", "test1"});
        //some code
        
    }
    
    private static ModelBean[] getPaymentBeans(ModelBean[] data, String[] test){
        //some code
        return ModelBean[] result;
    }
}
```

My Test class

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "oracle.jdbc.*", "javax.crypto.*", "javax.security.*", "sun.security.*", "javax.*", "org.xml.*"})
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})

 public void testErrorAndValidate() throws Exception {
  //some code
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
      PowerMockito.when(MyClass.class, "getPaymentBeans", ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenThrow(new NullPointerException()).thenCallRealMethod();
 
 //some code
 // some code for assertion
 }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: It would be difficult to provide the test as it is testing a whole service chain. This service chain call use lots of service and helper classes and I cannot include all those  in here, but I am testing a real world problem where while executing these service chain if there a failure then a separate process kicks in and process the sequence. 
In of the sequence handler class there is the private method is where I want to throw null pointer exception and subsequent service chain call passing through the same private method should be called as real method without throwing any error